# I am facing issu with select2 clear function to remove manual selected option

Tags: jquery-select2

select2 clear is not working when I am select option manually and clear t by js
Here is my function to clear select2 selected option

$('#select2_id option').removeAttr('selected');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#select2_id').val('').trigger('change);
```

Instead of

```
$('#select2_id option').removeAttr('selected');
```